# Android timer problem

Tags: android

I am using timer in my application for the background process and the timer runs successfully.
But the problem is that i have to stop timer when logout button is clicked , the logout button is in different Activity. i have used timer.cancel() but As the Both Activity different it does't work. so give some hint to stop timer.

Comment: Remember that making any object static makes it lifetime the same as the lifetime of your application. This a memory leak. There are better ways to communicate between activities.

Comment: thanks for the advice, so what is the second option for me rather then declare it static.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your Timer as `public static Timer timer;` and you will be able to access it in any Activity or class using `Acitivity_name.timer.cancel();`

Thanks...